# Linq query returns duplicate results when .Distinct() isn't used - why?

Tags: linq

When I use the following Linq query in LinqPad I get 25 results returned:

```
var result = (from l in LandlordPreferences
          where l.Name == "Wants Student" && l.IsSelected == true
          join t in Tenants on l.IsSelected equals t.IsStudent
          select new { Tenant = t});
result.Dump();
```

When I add `.Distinct()` to the end I only get 5 results returned, so, I'm guessing I'm getting 5 instances of each result when the above is used.

I'm new to Linq, so I'm wondering if this is because of a poorly built query? Or is this the way Linq always behaves? Surely not - if I returned 500 rows with `.Distinct()`, does that mean without it there's 2,500 returned? Would this compromise performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a poorly built query.
You are joining `LandlordPreferences` with `Tenants` on a boolean value instead of a foreign key.
So, most likely, you have 5 selected land lords and 5 tenants that are students. Each student will be returned for each land lord: 5 x 5 = 25. This is a [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) and has nothing to do with LINQ. A similar query in SQL would behave the same.

If you would add the land lord to your result (`select new { Tenant = t, Landlord = l }`), you would see that no two results are actually the same.

If you can't fix the query somehow, `Distinct` is your only option.

Comment: @Magnus: It has no effect at all on the result except for one edge case: There is not a single landlord that matches the criteria. Good point, will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I really want to achieve from this query is  to allow a landlord to select that they want only students returned from all available Tenants - but I can see where you're coming from - I imagine I'd pass to a method as a parameter that a Landlord wants a student, and then run the query based on the input.